# Qt Designer | Stretch column of table to fullest

Tags: qt, resize, qt-designer, qtablewidget

I am creating a simple GUI using Qt4 Designer.
I added a QTableWidget to my Dialog . I need only one column in my table and I want this column to stretch itself to the maximum width. But it seems to be of fixed width.

I tried setting setting property `horizontalHeaderStretchLastSection` to `true` from the editor but its not helping.
Can anyone please advise me which property should I be editing ?

Below is the screenshot .[image]

Below are rest of the properties of QTableWidget that I am using.

```
  <widget class="QDialogButtonBox" name="buttonBox">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>180</x>
     <y>460</y>
     <width>341</width>
     <height>32</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="orientation">
    <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
   </property>
   <property name="standardButtons">
    <set>QDialogButtonBox::Cancel|QDialogButtonBox::Ok</set>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QTableWidget" name="tableWidget">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>40</x>
     <y>70</y>
     <width>256</width>
     <height>192</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="sizePolicy">
    <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Expanding">
     <horstretch>0</horstretch>
     <verstretch>0</verstretch>
    </sizepolicy>
   </property>
   <property name="frameShadow">
    <enum>QFrame::Plain</enum>
   </property>
   <property name="midLineWidth">
    <number>1</number>
   </property>
   <attribute name="horizontalHeaderVisible">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </attribute>
   <attribute name="horizontalHeaderDefaultSectionSize">
    <number>107</number>
   </attribute>
   <attribute name="horizontalHeaderHighlightSections">
    <bool>true</bool>
   </attribute>
   <attribute name="horizontalHeaderStretchLastSection">
    <bool>true</bool>
   </attribute>
   <attribute name="verticalHeaderVisible">
    <bool>true</bool>
   </attribute>
   <attribute name="verticalHeaderShowSortIndicator" stdset="0">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </attribute>
   <attribute name="verticalHeaderStretchLastSection">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </attribute>
   <row>
    <property name="text">
     <string>New Row</string>
    </property>
   </row>
   <row>
    <property name="text">
     <string>rrr</string>
    </property>
   </row>
   <row>
    <property name="text">
     <string>gggg</string>
    </property>
   </row>
  </widget>
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on Ubuntu 14.04 and Qt 5.5 [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/gRhV8IP.png).

Comment: I have pasted entire ui xml here  http://justpaste.it/om8u   . Even in your screenshot column should not ending just after the text , it should stretch till the end.

Comment: ah, from the excerpt above I though `QDialogButtonBox` was your main widget.

Comment: @m.s. I don't want to stretch the table within its parent widget, I want to stretch the first column inside the table to cover the entire space inside the table. If you notice there is a lot of free white space to the right side of the first column , I want to cover that up with the first column.

Comment: What do refer to as the "first" column? the one with the text `New Row`, `rrr` and `gggg`? this is not a column, it is just the row description.

Comment: yes , the  one with text `New Row`,`rrr`,`gggg` is the first column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing the vertical header with the first column. If you want a table with just one column that fills the whole width, hide the vertical header and stretch the last column of the horizontal header:

[image: screenshot]

Then you should edit the table items, adding one column (say, called "First Column") and however many rows you need (it doesn't matter what you call those). This will enable the **Items** tab, where you can add the actual table contents. With that done, your table should look like this:

[image: screenshot]

I think it's worth pointing out here, though, that a one-column table with no headers is more or less equivalent to a ListWidget. So, given that a ListWidget has a much simpler API, maybe you should consider using that instead.